# Persistent cookies on classic ASP global.asa

Tags: iis, cookies, vbscript, asp-classic, global.asa

I would like to know if you can help me with the persistent cookies even when users closes the browser.

I'm running a web on IIS and asp, sessions are working fine, but each time that an user closes the browser it loose the session so the cart it's also lost.

I think it might be something related with the global.asa file? (I've saw answers on persistent cookies on global.asax but my web it's using global.asa)

This is my current global.asa file, any ideas?

```
Sub Application_OnStart
  Application("ActiveUsers") = 0
End Sub

Sub Session_OnStart
  Session.Timeout = 600
  Session("Start") = Now
  Application.Lock
  Application("ActiveUsers") = Application("ActiveUsers") + 1
  Application.UnLock
End Sub

Sub Session_OnEnd
 Application.Lock
 Application("ActiveUsers") = Application("ActiveUsers") - 1
 Application.UnLock
End Sub
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classic ASP Session ID Cookie Lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017493/classic-asp-session-id-cookie-lifetime)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the cookie will not exist when you close the browser if you didn't set a long timeout for it. So the session id will also lose even though the session is still exists in server(and will expire when it exceeds the timeout value).

So for your situation, you should set a long time for cookie timeout but not set the timeout for session as your code show. You can set the cookie timeout value on page as the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017493/classic-asp-session-id-cookie-lifetime) mentioned:

```
<script>
void function session_cookie_change() {
    var s,a;
    s=document.cookie.split(/\=/);            
    a=s[0];            
    var dtExpires = new Date();                
    dtExpires.setFullYear(1970,1,1);            
    a += ';
    // The expires parameter of the cookie 
    // is set to the previous date 
    expires=' + dtExpires.toGMTString();            
    a += '; path=/';             
    document.cookie=a;
}
</script>
<body onload='session_cookie_change()'>
```

Apart from this, you also need to pay attention to session id. Although the cookie doesn't be removed when close browser, it will use another session id when you re-open browser to connect to server. So you may also need to input `chrome://flags` in chrome address and search `samesite` and then disable it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017547/692942) pretty much covers it.

Comment: @user692942 Yes, so I mentioned in answer "as the document mentioned in comments show" and also provide my suggestion(at bottom) of pay attention to different session id.

Comment: Just don’t see the point in answering when it’s clearly a duplicate question, just flag and move on.